# How to change resolution on Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows, windows-ce, screen-resolution

I have an application that needs a resolution of 800x480, however, the device it seems that has a resolution of 480x800, but configurated to landscape insteado of portrait, so in this case the real resolution is 480x800 instead of 800x480.

How can I set the resolution of windows CE?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Do you have access to BSP? If so, try enabling/disabling the SYSGEN_QVGAP sysgen variable.

Comment: Do you need to change the resolution, or just rotate the screen?

Comment: Change the resolution, because if I rotate, for the applications the resolution still is the same. For example, if I have a 480x800 and rotate to landscape, the rsolution still is 480x800. I need 800x480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the "Angle" dword value under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\GDI\ROTATION
Valid values are 0 5A (90) B4(180) 10E(270)
The display driver must support rotation, but most of those implemented using GPE do.